# Problems running build command in Cordova application on Quasar Framework (On Windows)

Tags: vue.js, android-studio, gradle, quasar-framework

When running the command "quasar build -m cordova -T android" in my VueJS/Quasar application, to generate my apk, the following error is returned:

> FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
>
> ### 1: Task failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'C:\PROJETOS DA JCA\Connect\Connect-Front-end\src-cordova\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle'
>   line: 50
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
>
> > Failed to apply plugin 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'.
> > Could not create plugin of type 'AndroidMavenPlugin'.
> > > Could not generate a decorated class for type AndroidMavenPlugin.
> > > org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/MavenPomMetaInfoProvider
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   ==============================================================================
>
> ### 2: Task failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
>
> > compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   ==============================================================================
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
>
> You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation
> warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
>
> See
> https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 7s Command failed with exit code 1: C:\PROJETOS DA
> JCA\Connect\Connect-Front-end\src-cordova\platforms\android\gradlew
> cdvBuildRelease -b C:\PROJETOS DA
> JCA\Connect\Connect-Front-end\src-cordova\platforms\android\build.gradle
>
> App · Command "cordova" failed with exit code: 1  App · ⚠️  [FAIL]
> Cordova CLI has failed

- I am using the version of Gradle indicated in the Quasar Framework documentation (4.10.3).
- I installed JAVA JDK 8.
- Set all environment variables, as per Gadle doc, Quasar doc and Java guide.
- I installed Cordova.
- I installed Android Studio and downloaded the SDK's.

I don't know what could be going wrong. The error seems to me to be something related to Gradle. But I don't know what it can be. Can you help me ?

Comment: How did you manage to resolve this error?